# How to wire an ESP32-S2 Dev KitM-1 for power?

Tags: power, esp32, espressif

I'm putting an [Espressif ESP32-S2 Dev KitM-1](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Espressif-Systems/ESP32-S2-DevKitM-1?qs=DPoM0jnrROXzO8seOHN%252BOQ%3D%3D) into a project box. The box will have 12VDC power and a 5V buck converter for the Dev Kit.

Do I need to use the USB port to power the Dev Kit or can I directly wire 5VDC to the 5V pin (and ground, of course) to power it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32s2/hw-reference/esp32s2/user-guide-devkitm-1-v1.html) has

> Power Supply Options
>
> There are three mutually exclusive ways to provide power to the board:
>
> - Micro-USB Port, default power supply
> - 5V and GND pin headers
> - 3V3 and GND pin headers